# typo3 extension formhandler pregmatch

Tags: preg-match, typo3, html-formhandler

I am trying to validate a iban no for germany, but I cannot get pregMatch to work with formhandler. I cannot find a mistake and compared it with the formhandler documentation, but nothing helped. Maybe somebody has a hint for me. 
This is my code:

```
    debitiban.errorCheck {
        1 = pregMatch
        1.value = ^DE\d{2}\s?([0-9a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){4}[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}$
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is [directly passed](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-formhandler/repository/entry/trunk/Classes/Validator/ErrorChecks/Tx_Formhandler_ErrorCheck_PregMatch.php) on to PHPs [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function, so it has to be a valid [PCRE regex pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php). You are missing a delimiter charater in your expression. Try to surround the expression by slashes:

```
debitiban.errorCheck {
    1 = pregMatch
    1.value = /^DE\d{2}\s?([0-9a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){4}[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}$/
}
```